# iTextSharp не отображается кириллица

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

```
string outputPath = "output.pdf";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

            doc.Open();

            // Шрифт для русского текста
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN);

            // Текст на русском языке
            string russianText = "Привdddет";

            // Добавляем текст на страницу PDF
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(russianText, font);
            doc.Add(paragraph);

            doc.Close();
        }
```

После отработки кода, в pdf отображаются только английские буквы без русских

Comment: Шрифт, поддерживающий кириллицу используйте.

Comment: а times new roman не поддерживает кириллицу?

Comment: Вы думаете, что существует только русский вариант этого шрифта? Это не так.

Comment: можете подсказать, как здесь поставить нужный шрифт?
Я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: Без понятия, но попробуйте копать в сторону шрифтов с поддержкой кодировки UTF-8, или на худой конец Windows 1251.